# Explode string together with tags in between [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have the following sample string:

```
$string = 'I wish you a merry <span style="font-size: 14px;">Christmas</span> and a happy new <span style="font-size: 18px;">year</span>!'
```

Now I am trying to explode this string so that the output is:

```
$arr[0] = 'I wish you a merry '
$arr[1] = '<span style="font-size: 14px;">Christmas</span>'
$arr[2] = ' and a happy new '
$arr[3] = '<span style="font-size: 18px;">year</span>'
$arr[4] = '!'
```

I tried it with

```
$arr = explode('<span style="font-size: ', $string);
```

But of course then I include the whole string until the next opening `<span>`-Tag.

I also tried to use `preg_match_all` with a foreach loop over all used font-sizes:

```
preg_match_all('~\<span style="font-size:' . $fontSize . 'px;"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>~', $string, $output[$fontSize]);
```

But then the other strings which are not between the tags are not included. But I need them in the described order.

How can I convert that correctly to the given array? I need it for the PHP lib PDFlib which is not able to read HTML.

Comment: It's always nice to know what the purpose of an operation is.... it could even help to get better answers.

Comment: Right. I edited my question and added the purpose.

Comment: You know about `strip_tags()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is an easy and readable solution** (not the prettiest):

```
$string = 'I wish you a merry <span style="font-size: 14px;">Christmas</span> and a happy new <span style="font-size: 18px;">year</span>!';

$string = str_replace("<span", "|<span", $string);
$string = str_replace("</span>", "</span>|", $string);
```

**The string will end up like this:**

```
'I wish you a merry |<span style="font-size: 14px;">Christmas</span>| and a happy new |<span style="font-size: 18px;">year</span>|!'
```

**Now you can explode the string on "|":**

```
$arr = explode("|", $string);
```

Comment: clever solution

Comment: You can do both replacement in one go, like this: `$string = str_replace(['<span','</span>'], ['|<span','</span>|'], $string);`

Comment: Yes KIKO, that would be shorter en better but event tough I prefer the two lines so it's more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the tools for the job. Here's a way to do this using DOMDocument (with a little trick).

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();

$string = 'I wish you a merry <span style="font-size: 14px;">Christmas</span> and a happy new <span style="font-size: 18px;">year</span>!';
$dom->loadHTML("<div id='".($id=uniqid())."'>$string</div>"); //Trick, wrap in a div with a unique id.


foreach ($dom->getElementById($id)->childNodes as $child) { 
    echo $dom->saveHTML($child).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Outputs:

```
 I wish you a merry     
 <span style="font-size: 14px;">Christmas</span>    
  and a happy new     
 <span style="font-size: 18px;">year</span>    
 !
```

Of course instead of `echo $dom->saveHTML($child)` you can just put the results in an array e.g. `$array[] = $dom->saveHTML($child);`

[Live example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe98bb050603a0762f422030daeb1772cf8f5ff4)